# Storing Street Addresses and Postal Codes

Tags: database-design

I'm trying to decide how to store some address information. This is what I have in mind (it's in Django model form, but you should be able to read it)

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    province = models.ForeignKey(Province)
    data_source = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=DataSources.USER)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=12, null=True, blank=True)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=12, null=True, blank=True)
    feature_class = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True, blank=True)
    feature_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    population = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    elevation = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    time_zone = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    mod_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)

class Province(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=2, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)

class Country(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=2, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Address(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    postal_code = models.ForeignKey(PostalCode)

class PostalCode(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    data_source = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=DataSources.USER)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=12, null=True, blank=True)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=12, null=True, blank=True)
```

I've already got a database full of cities, provinces, countries, and postal codes. For the most part, users will only be entering addresses.

This way, if a user enters a postal code, I can populate the city, province and country fields automatically for him. But what if my data is out of date, or is incorrect? Then the user just has to update those fields with the correct information, and then I can update my database accordingly.

But what happens then if he enters someone else's postal code, and then updates the city to something incorrect? He's just broke someone else's address.

So maybe I should move the city field to the Address class instead? But then I can no longer look up the city from the postal code.

So then maybe I should just have cities in both models? But now I've got duplication. Is this still the best option?

Comment: And what are you going to when cities cross state lines and postal codes cross city or statelines (they certainly do in the US)?

Comment: @HLGEM: Didn't know they did... that could be problematic. Can you give an example of where that happens? That would mean I need to store the city and state in the Address.

Comment: Nvm. http://ask.metafilter.com/23195/Cities-that-span-two-or-more-states. And you know what? It's not actually an issue. I'll just have two entries for the same city, just with different states.

Comment: Postal Codes that cross.. I was hoping the "code" would be unique...but if I really had to, I could make (code,city) unique together instead.

Comment: Postal code 81601 contains CARDIFF, GLENWOOD, GLENWOOD SPRINGS, WEST GLENWOOD CO  It tends to happen frequently (my database query of our zip code table returned over 100,000 records) especially in areas low in population.

Comment: @Mark. The Canadian Postal code system is unique, well thought out.  THe American one is hopeless, you need to grab 7 digits at lest, not five.

Answer (score 3):

Not really.  You are mixing up two different functional aspects.

1. Normalise your data so that there is no duplication. otherwise your database is crippled.

   - Sure, you have to allow for cities that cross state boundaries, towns that have two pst codes, etc.
2. Security.  Why on Earth would you allow any person to update Reference (the tables that constitute static data that make up an Address) tables ?  That should be reserved for Admin users.  And periodically, you need to update the Reference tables from your local council or whatever.

Comment: Huh? (1) How? The way I've specified it, there is no duplication, but that's exactly whats causing the problems in the first place. (2) You wouldn't. That's the other problem. How do you handle incorrect data? Do you let the user update it? Does he have to file a bug and wait for an admin to fix it? What?

Comment: @Mark. Since when does non-duplication cause "problems" ??? (a city that crosses a state boundary, entered in two states, is **not** a duplicate). 2) well, if your admin only works on Fridays, sure, file a Data Entry request or whatever. I am drawing your attention to the fact the there is a large gap between the 5 tables presented, and a reasonable "address" group of columns; that you allow **any** person rather than qualified people to change Reference values in the Db; that you do not load the gap from Reference Authorities.

Comment: Look at [*this Model*](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/Order%20DM%20Advanced.pdf) which is loaded from council data; no suburbs or street names or postal codes are *entered* by the user, they are *chosen* from drop-downs; no waiting for Admins; user is not allowed to update Reference data.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA: You didn't explain that the city should be entered twice, once for each state. Now your solution sounds like the one I eventually arrived at.

Comment: @Mark.  I have no attachments. You can choose any model you like.  But please, at least load Suburbs and StreetNames from an Authority; and remove the possibility of daft users changing Reference data.

Comment: I don't have a database of street names, just cities and communities, which I got from geocoder.ca. Users won't be able to change reference data, but they'll be able to add new records if they're missing. These new records won't appear anywhere on the site until I've verified them. Sound good?

Comment: @Mark. That sounds better. But as long as you are not "loading Suburbs and StreetNames from an Authority", the site visitors will have to enter them manually, and you will be verifying an awful lot of Suburb names and Street names manually.  That info is usually available free.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you can keep the design.

If your city is incorrect, your users will update it. If you think the users could be wrong too, just wait for X persons to update your data with the same information the first user gave, then update your database accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm keeping the design and just putting the unique constraint on (postal_code,city), and (city,province) instead. That way the same entries can appear twice if they spill over to another region.